# String Overlay in Android

Tags: java, android, overlay, itemizedoverlay, overlays

is there anyway of creating a String overlay? Because I'm working on a project which I show the spots in the map, but I wanna also show some String identifing the spot, like an id, for example
att,
Andre Mariano

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder() instead of String. Example..

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("some string");
sb.append("more string");
Toast.makeText(this, sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I didn't understand, I'm asking if there is anyway of creating an Overlay (Map Overlay) with a String